# Artefacts when drawing textures

Tags: libgdx, transparency, alpha-blending

I am working on a level-based android game. The level is constructed of many blocks, all drawn with the same texture. Until now I didn't have any problems with drawing the different textures next to each other. However, when I draw a translucent rectangle over the level (in order to show a pause screen on top of it for example), I get artefacts on the places where the textures overlap. To be more clear I included a screenshot that clearly shows my issue: the regions where the textures of the different level blocks overlap do not have the same transparency as the rest of the rectangle.

[image]

As you can see, only when drawing the translucent rectangle on top of the level, the overlap is visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens with some MSAA or CSAA implementations.

Try disabling anti-aliasing and see if it goes away.

If that is the case you might need to force multi-sampling resolve before rendering your transparency.

The other solution would be to force some overlap of your tiles.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried to disable anti-aliasing, but this did not really solve the problem. I was still seeing these lines. I tried your other proposition (forcing some overlap of the tiles themselves), which solved the issue. Thanks.